# New to bootstrap,struggling with getting the pictures displayed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning to create an e-commerce website using `bootstrap` and after finally creating all the pages and linking all the pages , the various pictures are not being displayed. I do not know where I am going wrong. please help!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and post your code by pressing Ctrl+M and pasting code into the appropriate boxes.

Comment: can you show us code where  you referencing images, image path?

Comment: It has been a day since i am trying to upload the code but i am not able to.It just keeps on asking to add text or comments related to the code.Is there any other way to send the code.

Comment: Ashley... click edit in your post above. In the edit window press Ctrl-K or click the curly brackets and paste your code... to start off we need an example of your img tags

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some helpful hints to follow when posting questions. To display your code, copy and paste your code into the post window. Then, with all the code highlighted, press CTRL + K to have it formatted correctly.